# How can I run make on file update?

Tags: gnu-make

I would like to be able to watch the files in my project and have `make` run every time one of the targets gets updated (unless it's changed by `make` itself I suppose). This is a common feature in many build tools and I'm just curious if there's a way to do this with `make`.

Comment: What other build tools implements this "common feature" (i.e. automatic rebuilding of the whole project as soon as a single file changes)?  Usually, one types `make` whenever one wants to rebuild the project. Considering that build times may be long for certain projects, and that "building" may also involve running checks etc., I wonder if such a feature would be more of a nuisance than a boon.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have makes that are incremental and take seconds. ⅓ second or less with a typical change.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor So do I, and I have those that do not.

Comment: @Kusalananda so only use a tool when it makes sense. I would agree that modifying make to do it would be a bad idea. But having a tool to call make (if you think that it should), is a good idea.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, what do you do when some change requires modifications to more than one file? Running make after each file was changed would probably lead to lots of errors. Which you could of course just ignore, but anyway.

Comment: @ilkkachu that is why use of tools requires judgement. It you tell the computer to stop you doing something stupid, then you will not be able to do anything.

Comment: @Kusalanada I only have experience with Gulp. It doesn't rebuild the entire project when any file changes, but you can set up each task to watch the files that it uses and run whenever one of them changes. Since `make` has a mechanism for determining which targets need to be made again and which don't, I figured watching every file would effectively be the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `inotify-wait` I do this on a regular basis. (only done it on small projects, so no idea how it scales.)

`inotify-wait` will sleep until a file is touched (in some way, as specified in the options). It will then exit. It is event based (no polling), so uses no CPU when waiting. Put it in a wrapper script that calls make. There are a few race hazards, that can happen, so be careful.

Comment: So do you do something like `while true; do inotifywait ... && make; done`?

Comment: @mason. Yes that looks like it will work. But note the race hazard.